# How to check image and video dimensions on the backend Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

Hey I have the task of filtering through an array of items, each items contains a image url or a video file url, My task is to filter out all the items which are not squarish in dimension, I have a working snippet of code which is doing this on the front end, how ever once filtered I am unable to display the new items to the Page, even though I can console log the itemsarray and it has the filtered Items list,

I was returning a promise on each consecutive iteration while mapping the items, this worked just fine, and the items got pushed into the array as well a list of promises for each item, So I know when all the items have been filtered through.

```
function isImageSquare(url){
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function () {
      resolve(this.height / this.width < 1.2 && this.height / this.width > 0.8);
    }
    img.src = url;
  });
}

function isVideoSquare(url) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    // create the video element
    const video = document.createElement('video');

    // place a listener on it
    video.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", function () {
      // retrieve dimensions
      const height = this.videoHeight;
      const width = this.videoWidth;

      // send back result
      resolve(height / width < 1.2 && height / width > 0.8);
    }, false);

    // start download meta-datas
    video.src = url;
  }); 

const itemArray = [];
  const promises=[];
  data.map((item) => {
    if(item.itemType === "image" ||item.itemType === "audio"){
      isImageSquare(url).then((result) => {
//Result is true or false
        result&&itemArray.push(item)
        promises.push(result);
      })
    }
    if(item.itemType === "video"){
      isVideoSquare(item.videoUrl).then((result) => {
//Result is true or false
        result&&itemArray.push(item)
        promises.push(result);
      })
    }
  })
```

The problem I ran into is I cant use Promise.All to check whether all the promises are resolved and then render the items in react HTML, or jsx, I recieve the error saying expected HTML received a promise, my initial response was to create a usestate that would host the promise.all value which would be initally false and then trued when all the promise got resolved and I could simply usestate&&item.stuff That doesnt work either because the itemarray gets populated later on and I tried to use a useState array on the item array, but that doesnt seem to be working either, its giving a weird unrelated error of to many react players being initialiazed. I thought well, since this is just a next js app, and I can display items given to me already, I will just filter the list in the backend and get the filtered item list from a serverside api call, and than I found out image and video dont exist on server side as it is node.js and I cant check there dimensions on the server side, I have been stuck doing this for 1 and half days now, need help The best approach would be to just be able to filter through the items on the front end, and then display them.